# Detecting capsules from a 3D MRI stack of images

Tags: image-processing

I need to detect the 3D position and orientation of capsules from a 3D MRI stack of images.
Any ideas on how to perform this task?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try `ITK` https://itk.org

Comment: the question doesn't seem specific enough.  can you define it more by giving us some details of what approaches you are considering and constraints you have?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am not sure, but what I noticed is that with an ImageJ plugin (https://imagej.net/3D_Objects_Counter) I should be able to obtain a bounding box around my capsule and, therefore, identify its position and orientation. But I want to know if I can use a programming language (like Python or MATLAB) to obtain the same results. I noticed a lot of libraries for object recognition in 2D, but not in 3D.